# How to arrange my code block to make it work smooth and correct

Tags: arduino-uno

I currently working on my system that automatically water the plant based on the water requirement of the plant for one day . I have a java application that let the user input the water requirement of the plant and then the java application send it to arduino the arduino will receive the data and put it inside the variable and it will be use .. I use the following sensor/module ..

- SOIL MOISTURE 2 PCS.
- WATER FLOW SENSOR 2 PCS.
- SOLENOID VALVE 2PS
- WATER LEVEL SENSOR 1 PCS.
- HUMIDITY SENSOR 1 PCS.
- REAL TIME CLOCK DS3231

The data that the java app will send is the water requirements for 1 day for example 400ml , the 400ml will be used by the water flow sensor if the sensor reads that its already 400ml has pass in the tube the solenoid will close the pipe . And my system has a water tank the water sensor is attach to it and will check if the water in the tank is not low if low the arduino will send that data into the java app .. All the sensors reading will be save into database using the java application ..

Here is My Whole code for arduino , its not finish yet because i'm stuck thinking on how to arrange my code blocks . Sorry for my English please bear with me ..

```
#include <DS3231.h>

//PINS
#define MOISTURE1 A15
#define MOISTURE2 A14
#define WATERFLOW1 A13
#define WATERFLOW2 A12
#define HUMIDITY A11
#define RELAY1 9
#define RELAY2 8
#define ALARM 2

DS3231  rtc(SDA, SCL);
int DELAYNI = 1000;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
pinMode(MOISTURE1, INPUT);
pinMode(MOISTURE2, INPUT);
pinMode(WATERFLOW1, INPUT);
pinMode(WATERFLOW2, INPUT);
pinMode(HUMIDITY, INPUT);  
pinMode(RELAY1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(RELAY2, OUTPUT);

rtc.begin();

Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  //Some Code here to get the data send by java app and then assign it to each variable

  readMoistureStatus();
  readWaterLevel();
}
void readWaterLevel(){
  ///Some code here
}

void readMoistureStatus(){

 int  moistureOneSensorValue = analogRead(MOISTURE1);
 int  moistureTwoSensorValue = analogRead(MOISTURE2);

   // checking the moisture range for the first soil moisture
  if(moistureOneSensorValue >= 700){
    // in case of dry soil:
    RelayOne();


     delay(DELAYNI);
  }
  if((moistureOneSensorValue < 700) && (moistureOneSensorValue >= 300)){
    // in case of moist soil:

    delay(DELAYNI);
  }
  if(moistureOneSensorValue < 300){
    // in case of soggy soil:

    delay(DELAYNI);
  }
   // 
   // 
   // Checking the moisture range for the second soil moisture


  if(moistureTwoSensorValue >= 700){
    // in case of dry soil:
    RelayTwo();


     delay(DELAYNI);
  }
  if((moistureTwoSensorValue < 700) && (moistureTwoSensorValue >= 300)){
    // in case of moist soil:

    delay(DELAYNI);
  }
  if(moistureTwoSensorValue < 300){
    // in case of soggy soil:

    delay(DELAYNI);
  }

}


void RelayOne(){
  //Close or Open the Solenoid

  //Read the water flow if the set point is reach it will close the solenoid using the relay
}

void RelayTwo(){
  //Close or Open the Solenoid

 //Read the water flow if the set point is reach it will close the solenoid using the relay
}
```

Comment: And also how often the arduino read the sensors value ? Or I just let the user decide the interval of reading the sensor and then save to database

Answer (score 1):

I think that overall your code looks good but I don't understand why you need to log data every 1 seconds (DELAYNI = 1000; is approx 1 sec).
Although there's nothing wrong in placing the

```
if(moistureOneSensorValue >= ...)
...
...
```

codeblock in your readstatus(), it's best to separate this out into a dosomething function. Alternatively, you can read the moisture status in the `void loop()` itself and then place a `switch` case in the `doSomething()` function.

You can also use the data from the RTC to check moisture and do something:

```
void setup(){
...
time = DS3231.time(); //Time at the beginning
}

void loop(){

timeElapsed = now() - DS3231.time();//seconds elapsed

if (timeElapsed >= DELAYNI){
    moisture1 = analogRead(MOISTURE1); // Read ADC value
    moisture2 = analogRead(MOISTURE2); // Read ADC value
    updateDatabase(time, moisture1, moisture2, relay1, relay2); //update the moisture values and statuses of the relays to the database
    switchRelays(moisture1,moisture2); // switch relay1 and relay2 depending on vals
time = DS3231.time(); // Update the time

    } 

}
```